# Pandas: Weird transformation required

Tags: pandas

```
Name    Start           End   Units Place
Sam     04-03-2022  06-03-2022  2   CA
Uber    24-04-2022  27-05-2022  1   SVL
Twitter 26-04-2022  28-04-2022  2   FR
```

My dataframe is like above. I wish to duplicate each row by n times where n equal to the difference between Start and End entry. But while duplicating the Start has to increment by one each time. So, My output need to be something like below:

```
Name    Start   Units   Place
Sam 04-03-2022  2   CA
Sam 05-03-2022  2   CA
Uber    24-04-2022  1   SVL
Uber    25-04-2022  1   SVL
Uber    26-04-2022  1   SVL
Twitter 26-04-2022  2   FR
Twitter 27-04-2022  2   FR
```

I am starring at this for quite sometime. But, clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `pd.date_range` to each row then explode your dataframe:

```
# Not mandatory if it's already the case
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True)

date_range = lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End']-pd.DateOffset(days=1))
out = (df.assign(Start=df.apply(date_range, axis=1))
         .explode('Start', ignore_index=True).drop(columns='End'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Name      Start  Units Place
0       Sam 2022-03-04      2    CA
1       Sam 2022-03-05      2    CA
2      Uber 2022-04-24      1   SVL
3      Uber 2022-04-25      1   SVL
4      Uber 2022-04-26      1   SVL
5      Uber 2022-04-27      1   SVL
6      Uber 2022-04-28      1   SVL
7      Uber 2022-04-29      1   SVL
8      Uber 2022-04-30      1   SVL
9      Uber 2022-05-01      1   SVL
10     Uber 2022-05-02      1   SVL
11     Uber 2022-05-03      1   SVL
12     Uber 2022-05-04      1   SVL
13     Uber 2022-05-05      1   SVL
14     Uber 2022-05-06      1   SVL
15     Uber 2022-05-07      1   SVL
16     Uber 2022-05-08      1   SVL
17     Uber 2022-05-09      1   SVL
18     Uber 2022-05-10      1   SVL
19     Uber 2022-05-11      1   SVL
20     Uber 2022-05-12      1   SVL
21     Uber 2022-05-13      1   SVL
22     Uber 2022-05-14      1   SVL
23     Uber 2022-05-15      1   SVL
24     Uber 2022-05-16      1   SVL
25     Uber 2022-05-17      1   SVL
26     Uber 2022-05-18      1   SVL
27     Uber 2022-05-19      1   SVL
28     Uber 2022-05-20      1   SVL
29     Uber 2022-05-21      1   SVL
30     Uber 2022-05-22      1   SVL
31     Uber 2022-05-23      1   SVL
32     Uber 2022-05-24      1   SVL
33     Uber 2022-05-25      1   SVL
34     Uber 2022-05-26      1   SVL
35  Twitter 2022-04-26      2    FR
36  Twitter 2022-04-27      2    FR
```